# What does it print? Java

Tags: java

I have a doubt with an exercise that ask you to write what the programm print.

```
interface X { public void f(); }
interface Y { public char g(); }

class A implements Y, Z {
public void f() { System.out.print("A.f() "); }
public char g() { System.out.print("A.g() "); return 'A'; }
public void h() { System.out.print("A.h() "); }
public void m() { System.out.print("A.m() "); }
}

class B implements X {
public void f() { System.out.print("B.f() "); }
}

class C extends B implements Y {
public void f() { System.out.print("C.f() "); }
public char g() { System.out.print("C.g() "); return 'C'; }
}

public class Print{
public static void main (String args[]) {
    Y y = new C(); 
    X x = (B)y; 
    x.f(); 
    y.g();
System.out.println("End!");
    }
}
```

My doubt is why the x.f() print C.f() and not B.f. 
The cast `X x = (B)y`doesn't create a variable x with static type "X" and dynamic type "B"?

Comment: One thing that'd help other people debug your code is making use of reasonable identifiers. Naming your variables c, b, f makes it really hard for others to keep track of your code.

Comment: Because the function `f()` is already overriden..

Comment: @Taslim This is the text of the exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cast X x = (B)y doesn't create a variable x with static type "X" and dynamic type "B"?

No.

I suppose by "static type" you mean the type that compiler sees, and "dynamic type" is the actual type of the object at runtime.

Casting is purely a compile time thing, so it doesn't affect what the runtime type (dynamic type, in your words) is. Casting is basically saying

> "Hey compiler, I assert this object `y`'s type will be convertible to `B` at runtime, so please treat it as such as compile time as well"

Here, the casting expression `(B)y` evaluates to a value of type `B`, then it is implicitly converted to `X` because you assigned it to `x`.

So the compile time type for `x` is `X` as you said, but the runtime type is the same as the runtime type for  `y`, which is `C`.